# What exactly do angle-brackets do in postgresql insert

Tags: postgresql, insert, brackets

I have encountered for 1st time the angle brackets in this context, it is auto-generated code from pgAgent:

```
INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_jobstep (jstid, jstjobid, ...)
 SELECT <StpId>, <JobId>, ...
```

Intuitively, it looked like this is syntax for columns with defined sequence (e.g. datatype serial).
However, only the 1st column **jstid** is serial, the 2nd column **jstjobid** is integer in that table.

Can anyone explain, or better yet, point me to explanation in official documentation for what the angle brackets mean, and what they do exactly ?

Comment: They do nothing, that is invalid SQL. Maybe they indicate placeholders which need to be replaced with real column names.

Comment: Then I assume pgAgent eventually replaces the placeholders in the query shown in UI, before actually running it. Seems reasonable. I didn't think it was valid sql either, but I wanted to confirm, thanks.